# Efficient method comparing 2 different tables columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, string-matching

[image: Example_List]

Hi all guys,

I have got 2 dfs and I need to check if the values from the first are matching on the second, only for a specific column on each, and save the values matching in a new list. This is what I did but it is taking quite a lot of time and I was wandering if there's a more efficient way. The lists are like in the image above from 2 different tables.

```
for x in df_bd_names['Building_Name']:
    for y in df_sup['Source_String']:
        if x == y:
            matching_words_sup.append(x)
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you're working in pandas I would avoid looping over each row of the dataframe. I would make it an inner join (using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging)). This will output all the common rows between the 2 dataframes.

Comment: Hi @anddt,

Thanks for your reply.
Do you know if I can merge only 1 column from the first table with one column with the second as the 2 dfs are different in structure and I am comparing only one column on each.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create both dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Building_Name': ['Exces', 'Excs', 'Exec', 'Executer', 'Executor']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Source_String': ['Executer', 'Executor', 'Executor Of', 'Executor For', 'Exeutor']
})
```

Perform inner merge between dataframes and convert first column to list:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Building_Name', right_on='Source_String', how='inner')['Building_Name'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['Executer', 'Executor']
```

Comment: many thanks, it works perfectly and is way more efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
    def __init__(self, df1, df2):
        self.df1 = df1
        self.df2 = df2
    def compareDFsEffectively(self):
        np1 = self.df1.to_numpy()
        np2 = self.df2.to_numpy()
        np_new = np.intersect1d(np1,np2)
        print(np_new)
        df_new = pd.DataFrame(np_new)
        print(df_new)
```

Comment: Numpy array is quite fast and can generate results quickly.